# Can you use Orchard CMS with Entity Framework 5 instead of NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, orchardcms

Can you use Orchard CMS with Entity Framework 5 instead of NHibernate?

I'm writing an MVC 4 Code First app and don't want to have to learn NHibernate - I would like all my projects to be consistent and use Entity Framework 5+

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Thanks.

EF seems to be the way things are headed now as it's Microsoft's own ORM - I think it would make sense to support it in Orchard?

Comment: The choices that Orchard makes are not dictated by Microsoft. Orchard is an independent, community-driven project. nHibernate was and still is the best fit. It would take a gigantic amount of work to change it now, for no clear benefit. The move to document databases will happen sooner than this. Don't count on it.

Comment: I understand you're independent. The fact MS are pushing EF now though will mean that it becomes the most common DRM solution people use in .NET going forward.

I guess it would be a nightmare to update it - in the same way updating Umbraco to MVC is a nightmare...

Comment: For what it's worth I switched to Composite C1 - which is super simple and easy to use.

Comment: I think you can use EF within your module, as Piotr said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543595/will-orchard-cms-support-mvc4-with-entity-framework. However, in my opinion, learning nHibernate takes very little and will benefit you in any case. Moreover you will have to learn almost nothing since all you need is already provided within Orchard: persistence through generic repos and auto mapping through simple conventions, you just need to create your migration and you are golden.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to know how nhibernate works, using the Orchard content manager and standard Linq is enough in almost all scenario's. We use entity framework in our other projects. And the  migrations in Orchard are simple but powerfull. Think about it.

Comment: I am undertaking a large site that needs CMS functionality. All our other sites use Entity Framework so ideally we would stick to that.

EF seems to be the way things are headed now - I think it would make sense to support it in Orchard?